# Inner Join error (multi-part identifier could not be bound error only on using)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I wrote the following query in my stored procedure on SQL SERVER 2008 :
 (I purposely truncated the Table names and also made the query easier to read)

1)

```
select Pr.Id from D D , DP DP, P P, Pr Pr
where D.Id = DP.Id AND DP.Id = P.Id AND P.Id = Pr.Id;
```

and it works completely fine , but when I write the same query using Inner Joins

2)

```
select Pr.PId  from D D
INNER JOIN DP DP ON D.Id = DP.Id
INNER JOIN P P ON DP.Id = P.Id 
INNER JOIN Pr Pr ON P.Id = Pr.Id
```

It throws an error : The multi-part identifier "Pr.Id" could not be bound.

3) 
I again tried another version :

```
select Pr.Id  from Pr Pr
INNER JOIN P P ON Pr.Id = P.Id
INNER JOIN DP DP ON P.Id =  DP.Id
INNER JOIN Dealer D ON DP.Id = D.Id
```

I fail to understand why 1 & 3 work whereas the 2 doesnt work .
Although I feel all of them mean the same thing.

Comment: Realizing you are using aliasing in your code and that you shortened things to make it easier for us to see so things aren't exactly the way they are in real life. On part two you don't actually have an alias listed for PR.  Is it there in your real code?  Or are you actually using the full name across the board?

Comment: @KennethFisher : Thank you . There is a typo that I made on Part 2 while posting the question on StackOverflow. I am using the full names in my real query, but I shortened the Table names to the Alias Names in the question.

Comment: Ok, next question, is there any way you can post the actual FROM clause?  The whole thing?  Or even better the whole query.  Just based on what you are posting so far you shouldn't be seeing an error.

Comment: Has your question been answered? Or do you require more help?

Comment: @Kenneth Fisher & Tom.Bowen89 : I apologize for not getting back to you both . I am currently using the 3) version of the query and it works . I will do a little more investigation about why the 2) version doesn't work and get back to the page again.

Answer (score 3):

Since the distinction between examples 2) and 3) is the location of the `Pr` table, and since your error references `Pr.Id`, my assumption is that you are trying to use a column from `Pr` before you reference the table in your sequence of joins.

A simple example:

```
select a.ID
from a
join b on a.id = b.id and a.id = c.id <--- referenced too early.
join c on c.id = b.cid
```

Would give you the error:

```
The multi-part identifier "c.id" could not be bound.
```

Since you're trying to reference the table alias before it appears in your sequence of joins.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need an alias on your Pr table? I can't tell as you have shorted your table names. Posting the code as it is will help us identify the problem.

Try:

```
select Pr.PId  from D D
INNER JOIN DP DP ON D.Id = DP.Id
INNER JOIN P P ON DP.Id = P.Id 
INNER JOIN Pr Pr ON P.Id = Pr.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2) you have

> select Pr.PId

While in 1) and 3) you have

> select Pr.Id

does Pr has the PId column? or just a typo?